# Installing python using Dockerfile not working

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to run the below Dockerfile contents on ubuntu image.

```
    FROM ubuntu
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y python
    RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
    RUN pip install flask
    COPY app.py /opt/app.py
    ENTRYPOINT FLASK_APP=/opt/app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

But im getting the below error at layer 3

```
tep 1/7 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 549b9b86cb8d
Step 2/7 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 78d87d6d9188
Step 3/7 : RUN apt-get install -y python
 ---> Running in a256128fde51
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python
```

Athough while i run the below command individually

**sudo apt-get install -y python**

it's successfully getting installed.

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: Your Dockerfile does not contain the command that is failing (i.e. `add-apt-repository`). Your build fails at step 3/ **8** where your current Dockerfile contains only **7**.  Meanwhile, the error is pretty straightforward: `add-apt-repository` does not exist. You need to install it. See duplicate link above.

Comment: I did install add-apt-repository but getting the below error after that. The docker file remain same as originally posted in the question.                      step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 549b9b86cb8d
Step 2/7 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 78d87d6d9188
Step 3/7 : RUN apt-get install -y python
 ---> Running in a256128fde51
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python

Comment: I modified the question with the output i'm getting. The issue still persists.

Comment: Try `docker build --no-cache .` Your step 2 is using cached `apt-get update` whcih probably needs to be refreshed. Moreover, you should consider using a single `RUN` expression here cleaning up apt lists at the end.